# prepareForSegue:sender: gets wrong sender

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I’ve got a UITableView that gets data from an array of strings which represent a headline, an abstract, and a destination URL. When the user selects a cell, the app segues to a View Controller containing a web view.

The problem is that no matter which cell gets selected, the data passed is always the first cell...

(`self.mockData` is a dummy hard-wired array that I’m using until I get to work on the model)

Code below, any help very much appreciated.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"destinationWebView" sender:[self tableView:self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"destinationWebView"]) {
        MyCustomWebPageViewController *destinationViewController = [segue destinationViewController];
        if ([destinationViewController canPerformAction:@selector(setArticleUrl:) withSender:self]) {
            if (self.urlOut) {
                self.urlOut = nil;
            }
            NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:sender];
            NSString *urlString = [[self.mockData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] objectAtIndex:2];
            self.urlOut = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
            [destinationViewController setArticleUrl:self.urlOut];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You should be asking the tableview for its cell, not asking your data source method directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think replacing your `performSegueWithIdentifier` line with the following would work:

`[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"destinationWebView" sender:[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]];`

This works as you're now asking the `UITableView` for the cell, as opposed to the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate method (as also pointed out in the original question comment).

Comment: Yikes! Thanks, that certainly worked... Don't even know what that was or how it got there. Time for a break I think. Will mark as correct as soon as SO allows me.